# Package does not exists - Java

Tags: java

This is a very trivial question, but stack doesn't seem to have very many good answers on it. (see below for the tree structure)

in `start.java` I am doing: `import web.*`, but it cant find the package web. All the classes in web are either `package web.exceptions;` or `package web;` or even `package web.interfaces;`

And I thought for importing packages you do: `import path.to.package.name.*;` where star imports all classes of that package, or you could do `import path.*;` which would import all packages and sub packages and their classes.

What am I missing?

The exact error is:

```
start.java:1: error: package web does not exist
```

**The class in question is:**

```
package src; // right package?

import web.*;

public class Start{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if(args[0].startsWith("--port")){
          String[] argument = args[0].split("=");
          WebServer webServer = new WebServer(argument[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Tree Path**

I moved `Start.java` to `web/` and changed the `import web.*;` to `import server.*;` now it doesn't know where server is, or what it is ...

```
.
└── src
    ├── MainClass.txt
    └── web
        ├── Start.java
        └── server
            ├── WebServer.java
            ├── exceptions
            │   └── WebServerException.java
            └── interfaces
                └── WebServerInterface.java
```

Comment: Sublime. Thats about it.

Comment: import path.* will NOT import classes from path.to package. path.* will only import classes inside path.

Comment: web is a folder with folders with the names interfaces and expcetions

Comment: Go to the `ApplicationName` folder and type `tree` in cmd and copy paste the folder structure.

Comment: im on a mac obvi that isn't gonna work ... whats the proper command

Comment: [tree](http://superuser.com/questions/359723/mac-os-x-equivalent-of-the-ubuntu-tree-command) command in Mac

Comment: Updaed OP please see OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"or you could do import path.**; *which would import all packages and sub packages and their classes"*

This is totally wrong. If we say

```
import java.util.*;
```

we mean that import all classes from `java/util/` path. If what you are saying is true then we can just say

```
import java.*;
```

even

```
import *.*;
```

and it will import all classes under JDK. **NO IT'S NOT**.

---

After OP's EDIT

`Start.java` is under `src/web/` folder. So the package statement of `Start.java` should be

```
package web;
```

Now if you want to use `WebServer.java` use

```
import web.server.WebServer;
```

Now if you want to use `WebServerException.java` use

```
import web.server.exceptions.WebServerException;
```

Now if you want to use `WebServerInterface.java` use

```
import web.server.interfaces.WebServerInterface;
```

And please read basic tutorial before you write any code.

Read about [Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html).