# Selenium compilation error due to bad class file

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

My Java web application is upgraded from `JDK 1.6` to `JDK 1.8` version and I am updating the test environment to use the updated `Selenium` components as well.

Below mentioned are the updated Jars which I included in the `pom.xml`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-leg-rc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I run a Job in `Jenkins`, it is throwing a compilation error as mentioned below.

```
        [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
        [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
        [ERROR] D:\Jenkins\workspace\WIDFLY-trunk\src\test\java\com\company\test\dragon\acceptance\test\shiftscheduling\switchautm\switchtimes\SwitchingTimesAbsTest.java:[3,-1] cannot access org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory
        bad class file: org\openqa\selenium\support\PageFactory.class(org\openqa\selenium\support:PageFactory.class)
        class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0
        [INFO] 1 error
        [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Total time: 31.294s
        [INFO] Finished at: Mon Dec 04 CET 2017
        [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/31M
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project test: Compilation failure
        [ERROR] D:\Jenkins\workspace\WIDFLY-trunk\src\test\java\com\company\test\dragon\acceptance\test\shiftscheduling\switchautm\switchtimes\SwitchingTimesAbsTest.java:[3,-1] cannot access org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory
        [ERROR] bad class file: org\openqa\selenium\support\PageFactory.class(org\openqa\selenium\support:PageFactory.class)
        [ERROR] class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0
        [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

What is that I am missing? I think it has a problem with `selenium-support` jar version but I have tried with lower version too and I am getting the same error.

*Note*: If I execute directly using `maven` in CMD prompt I am not getting any errors. Jenkins job execution only throws this error.

Kindly help please.

Comment: Check you local maven repo.I think the selenium support jar in you local doesnt have `org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory` class i guess.

Comment: @SudhaVelan, the class is available alright. The problem is with version.

Comment: @DeeJay007 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906659/java-compiling-error-in-command-prompt-class-file-has-wrong-version-52-0-shoul

Comment: It turned out to be that Configure System in Jenkins needs to updated with the JDK 1.8 version too. This was the reason for the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error does gives us a hint with what's going wrong as :

```
cannot access org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory
```

and

```
class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0
```

The most likely solution for you will be to :

- Upgrade **`JDK`** to recent version **`JDK 8u151`**
- Use recent version of **`Selenium Maven Dependencies`** current being **`v3.8.1`**
- Try to use **`selenium-java`** dependency only.

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- If you are using **`RemoteWebDriver implementation`**, you still need to start a Selenium server. The best way is to download the **`selenium-server-standalone.jar`** from the [**`Selenium Downloads page`**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) and just use it. You can also embed the Selenium Server into your own project, if you add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- **`selenium-support`** is no longer a valid dependency so you can remove it.
- Do **`maven clean`** and **`maven install`**
- Re-Run your **`Test`**

Comment: Thanks a lot @DebanjanB, I removed selenium-support and included selenium-server jars in the pom.

Comment: the real issue is JDK 1.8 is not included in the Jenkins Configuration. This is the reason why it worked with maven CMD and not in Jenkins.